# Is there a way to add margin to an icon in a span class or id to make it align at the left side of a html file?

Tags: html, css, html-heading

Tried adding margin right to an icon set to be in front of my  `<h1>` attribute but the icon keeps aligning to the center and not after the heading.

`Sammycode` then the `icon` with no space or margin in between the tag attributes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For debugging questions please edit your question to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I see you have the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=23262652) badge. Did you not read [ask]?